# error with sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i tried without single quotes and with it does not work.

```
$insert_query="INSERT INTO users_line
(name,surname,company_name,tel_number,cell_number,email,location,main_image,about_us)


VALUES('$name','$surname','$company_name','$tel_number','$cell_number','$email','$location','$main_image','$about_us')";
    if(mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query==true)){
        echo " <script>alert('successfully Posted') </script> ";

    } else{ echo  " h1> Did not work </h1>";
```

Comment: really couldnt get this point `i tried without single quotes and with it does not work. ` please clarify it

Comment: if(mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query) == true); see the difference?

Comment: So what is the error? You are passing in the boolean false instead of the query string with `$insert_query==true`...

Comment: Explain your question otherwise you will be downvoted

Comment: the error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: And that's why sane people leave whitespaces around their operators! `if (mysqli_query(... == true)) ...`

Comment: Try to `var_dump($insert_query)`. Those single quotes might cause problem

Comment: its fixeddd. how do i mark correct one? its the was the ==true

Comment: Changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not magically fix your SQL injection problems. Use prepared statements and bind variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`$connect->query($insert_query)` to run the query.

Comment: thanks man, sorry another question , how do i stop a duplicate post?

Comment: You are welcome, one way is having a primary key that uniquely identifies each post and let the db do the rest. The other way is to run a select query for the unique values in a post before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$insert_query="INSERT INTO
users_line        (name,surname,company_name,tel_number,cell_number,email,location,main_image,about_us)
VALUES('$name', '$surname','$company_name', '$tel_number', '$cell_number', '$email', '$location', '$ main_image', '$about_us')";

mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query);
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0){
 echo "It is working";
 }
 else{
 echo "Not Working!";
```

You had `echo  " h1> Did not work </h1>";` that should be `echo  "<h1> Did not work </h1>";`